# Why use Vagrant and Chef?

Tags: git, virtualbox, chef-infra, vagrant

I have a limited understanding at this point so my question may not make sense...

Why should I use Vagrant and Chef? **Why not just use Virtualbox cloning?**
I get that Vagrant allows me to make virtual machines based off already created boxes but why wouldn't I just make a virtual machine with virtualbox install my dependicies than clone that machine than save the clone to something like dropbox and allow my team to use the clone to work from?  I think Chef allows me to make specific setup of sever applications reproducible? But again, wouldn't my cloned virtual machine cover that?

Comment: Try use cloning. It will work great and be a lot simpler than learning chef.... However... you'll discover that you'll start making clones of clones... Eventually you'll need to upgrade a package in the original clone and ultimately you'll completely lose track and give up in frustration. This is what chef gives you. Version control over the various CM tweaks we make to base OS images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do all the things (create, destroy, export, mount shared folder, ssh into the VM, etc.) with a single command line in Vagrant. That's why it easier than to click through the GUI. And that's what (most) developers like.

Especially when it comes to [provisioners](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html), Vagrant saves a lot more time, as it takes over the whole setup of Chef, Puppet, etc. for you, mounts the data folders of the provisioners and (can only speak of Chef) allows you to directly assign the roles and recipes a VM should have.

Since Vagrant 1.1, different [providers](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/index.html) are supported. So VirtualBox is not the only supported virtualisation anymore.

Comment: Thanks StephenKing! So if I'm understanding this correctly, I could accomplish the same thing with the method I mention i.e. providing a VM clone file to peers but it would take me longer to setup than if I were to learn how to use vagrant and chef?  Is the amount of time savings really worth learning these 2 technologies?

Comment: Chef gives you a lot more (infrastructure as code, tests for that code, development machines match production machines and so on). Sure, it will cost a severe amount of time.
To just create a VM for your devs, Chef might be really overkill. I'd recommend you to just start with Vagrant. You can set the base box URL to your machine and then your colleagues just have to get the `Vagrantfile` and run `vagrant up` and it will spin up the machine (after it's downloaded when the box image isn't locally available).